# AVD show nothing except black screen

Tags: android

My AVD cannot display anything except the black screen. The methods I have tried are as follows:

1. Long press the power button to turn on

2.Modify the AVD configuration file, change avd.ini.encoding to ISO-8859-1

I am using Android Studio 4.1 and the Android version of AVD's Visual Devices is Android 9 (API 28).
There is no error message in the Event log

Comment: are you using x86 images or arm?

Comment: I'm using x86 image

Comment: so consider creating a new emulator (with default settings). also try other API versions to see if the problem persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wipe data of emulator in AVD Manager and start the emulator again